# Remove enclosing html tags from selection in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am working on a custom CMS and want to be able to select a section of HTML displayed for editing in a textarea and replace any enclosing tags with another tag. For instance, I may want to select a paragraph element and turn it into an h3 with one click, leaving any other tags untouched.

I have implemented [rangyinputs](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/wiki/Documentation) to allow getSelection/replaceSelectedText operations on textareas, and so far I have this:

```
function add_html_tag(target_ID, replace_tag) {
  $(target_ID).focus();
  $(target_ID).replaceSelectedText('<' + replace_tag + '>' + $(target_ID).getSelection().text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"") + '</' + replace_tag + '>');
}
```

This works OK but it removes ALL tags from the target text, not just the enclosing ones so any other tags within the selected text would also be removed.

Any ideas, I think it will just involve changing the regex in the replace statement. Since the textarea contains just plain text I can't use jQuery methods such as unwrap. Obviously doing regex operations like this on HTML is error prone, but for now I will presume users select the text correctly!

Comment: You should probably not use Regex to parse HTML.  See this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

this demo turns "A" tags into "LINK" tags; invalid, but shows the functionality you describe:

```
function add_html_tag(target_ID, replace_tag, new_tag_name) {
  var elm=$("#"+target_ID).focus()[0];
  elm.value=elm.value.replace(  new RegExp("<(\\\/?)"+replace_tag+"\\b", "gi"), "<$1"+new_tag_name);
}

add_html_tag(textAreaID, "a", "link");
```

Comment: Close, but is there a way of altering my code so that only the enclosing tags - whatever they are - are affected?